# How to add values to a key using Firebase?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is some code I have to initialize Firebase:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref('names');
var data = {
  userName: Elbert
}
ref.push(data);
```

Although I understand how to retrieve a unique key, I don't know how to push new data to that unique key. Specifically, I'm trying to add a child to the unique key under userName. I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

[image of data tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM2bN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume when you say that you would like to add a child to the unique key you mean along side rather than under userName as userName is a value itself, e.g. adding an email such as:

```
  names
    -L2Btcm5y1Nm0mCXi-E_
        userName: Elbert
        email: some@email.com
```

To do this you can either set the full data value under the unique key, i.e.:

```
var ref = database.ref('names/-L2Btcm5y1Nm0mCXi-E_');
var data = {
  userName: 'Elbert',
  email: 'some@email.com'
};
ref.set(data);
```

Or you can get a reference directly to the key you would like to set, i.e.:

```
var ref = database.ref('names/-L2Btcm5y1Nm0mCXi-E_/email');
ref.set('some@email.com');
```

Comment: That completely answered my question. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain.